# Como concateno este php

Tags: php

como puedo concatenar es `echo` dentro del div, de este modo que lo hago no me lo imprime dentro del div.

```
$filtradorHtml .= "<div class=\"container center margBlog1 pull-right\" style=\"padding: 0;\">";
   echo $filtrador->links();
$filtradorHtml .= "</div>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no te lo concatena porque no estas interactuando con la variable `$filtradorHtml`, deberia ser asi:

```
$filtradorHtml .= "<div class=\"container center margBlog1 pull-right\" style=\"padding: 0;\">";
$filtradorHtml .=$filtrador->links();
$filtradorHtml .= "</div>";
echo $filtradorHtml;
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, funciona perfecto, pero el `echo` lo tube que quitar si no me repetia dos veces el contenido